# What do you call an interval that includes a boundary of a restricted domain?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

In mathematical writing, what do you call an interval at the end of another interval? Here is an example usage:

Theorem: Let B be a subset of interval [0,1]. ...

Proof: We first prove the theorem when B is ___, that is, B = [0,x] or B = [x,1] for some x in [0,1]. ...

I'm not sure if there is a mathematical term for this. Would "an end interval" work?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "a boundary subinterval" is a better choice. There is no standard term for this, but at least one can say that B is a subinterval in this sentence; and "boundary" is more context-related than "end", since in mathematics "end" usually means something else. Also boundary has more scientific flavor as an adjective.